# Filtering results of JSON Object

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, object

```
var employees = {
"staff": [
  {"name": "Bob", "gender": "Male"},
  {"name": "Sue", "gender": "Female"},
  {"name": "Eric", "gender": "Male"},
  {"name": "Jo", "gender": "Female"}    
  ]
}
```

After iterating through this json structure, is there a method to selectively delete an entire row based on the gender selection? Ideally I'd like to have a new object but without any Males, for example.

Comment: just an fyi, your question has nothing to do with json. You may have retrieved the above object as json, but it is no longer json. This distinction may help you find an answer to similar problems in the future.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's the `.filter()` function:

```
employees.staff = employees.staff.filter(function(e) { return e.gender !== "Male"; });
```

The `.filter()` method is available for arrays in newer versions of JavaScript (modern browsers). For older browsers, [there is a polyfill available](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter#Compatibility).

Answer (score 2):

use [$.grep()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.grep/) - [Array.filter()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) is not used because of [IE < 9 support](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter#Browser_compatibility)

```
var females = $.grep(employees.staff, function (obj) {
    console.log(this, arguments)
    return obj.gender == "Female"
})
console.log(females)
```

Another solution is to use [Array.filter()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) with the [pollyfill](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter#Compatibility)

Answer (score 0):

```
employees.staff = filter(employees.staff, "Female");

function filter(data, filter) {
    return data.filter(function(row) {
        return row.gender === filter;
    });
}
```